# Im trying to get an image to the left side of a text box

Tags: html, css

Can anyone tell me what wrong with the css? The image appears at the bottom of the text box

```
<img src="husitsmotors.png" alt="Husqvarna FC 450 Dzinējs" style="float: right;width: 200px;">
```

And this is the css for the text box, both are in the same div.

```
.dzinejs {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    margin-right: 100px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 90%;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-style: normal;
    padding-top: 2rem;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 250px;
}
```

Most of the things I have tried resulted in either nothing happening or it getting more messed up. If I take it out of the dzinejs div then I cant get the image to align with the text.

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] first and then read [ask]. After that edit your question accordingly and provide debugging details in the form of a [repro].

Comment: You need to show us relevant HTML as it will depend on the structure and ordering of that what the effect of the float will be.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can do it like this

```html
<div class="dzinejs ">

        <p>
             Your text 
        </p>

        <img src="husitsmotors.png" alt="">
</div>

  <style>
  .dzinejs {
  display: flex;
}

.dzinejs img {
  width:4em;
  height:4em;
}
  </style>
```

```
.dzinejs {
  display: flex;
}

.dzinejs img {
  width:4em;
  height:4em;
}
```

```html
<div class="dzinejs ">

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. 
           Dolores hic pariatur ipsa accusamus similique ullam! Quis nulla 
           hic delectus reprehenderit ad magni accusantium fugit laboriosam 
           fugiat qui! Doloribus, beatae deleniti!
        </p>

        <img src="husitsmotors.png" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

just replace float right to `float: left;` in `img` tag

```css
.dzinejs {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    margin-right: 100px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 90%;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-style: normal;
    padding-top: 2rem;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 250px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="Husqvarna FC 450 Dzinējs" style="float: left;width: 200px;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes I second you can replace **float:right to float:left;** in img tag

or wrap the parent div with **container** class by giving

```
.container{
   display: flex;
 } 
<div class="container">
  <img src="pic_trulli.jpg" alt="Husqvarna FC 450 Dzinējs" style="float: 
 right;width: 200px;">
  <div class="dzinejs">
  <!-- Text content here -->
 </div>
```